# will renaming iptables mean I have no firewall after a reboot?

Tags: iptables

I'm having some issues accessing my VPS due to a combination of things. Serial console via my VPS control panel isn't accepting input either so my VPS host has offered to mount my file system on the host node and do whatever I need to get in.

Will renaming iptables to iptables.bak, remounting the file system and booting the machine start it up with no firewall rules in place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you're referring to the `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` file on a RHEL 6 or clone system, renaming that file as you specified should result in your system having no firewall rules in place when it boots.

Comment: It is indeed CentOS 6.4. Thank you sir